# Compass encoding error when using rvm and ruby 2.0.0

Tags: ruby, compass-sass

I've been using compass (sass) with grunt-contrib-compass on ruby 1.8 without any problems. My app is not a ruby app: just a folder with jade/js/scss (...grunt...) => html/js/css.

After installing and using ruby 2.0.0 with rvm, some encoding config seems to have changed since all Swedish characters `å`, `ä`, `ö` in any .scss file give an `Invalid US-ASCII character`-error when running `grunt compass`.

Where do I set this encoding property? In ruby install path? In compass install path? In application path?

Answer (score 0):

The [SASS documentation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#encodings) at says:

> Encodings
>
> When running on Ruby 1.9 and later, Sass is aware of the character
>   encoding of documents. By default, Sass assumes that all stylesheets
>   are encoded using whatever coding system your operating system
>   defaults to. For many users this will be UTF-8, the de facto standard
>   for the web. For some users, though, it may be a more local encoding.
>
> If you want to use a different encoding for your stylesheet than your
>   operating system default, you can use the @charset declaration just
>   like in CSS. Add @charset "encoding-name"; at the beginning of the
>   stylesheet (before any whitespace or comments) and Sass will interpret
>   it as the given encoding. Note that whatever encoding you use, it must
>   be convertible to Unicode.

If you are using MacOS or Linux, you can see and change your system encoding by running `locale`:

```
locale
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
...
```

You could try setting your encoding that way (see `man local`).  Or try the advice in the second paragraph: add a `@charset 'utf-8';` line at the start of your SASS file.